# When do I use V for Ü in Pinyin programs

Tags: pinyin

I use a program called Sougou, which is very poopular in China I think. Sometimes I use the Microsoft pinyin language option.

Sougou is very good at guessing my characters based on context, but sometimes I have to click through to find my character, especially when it's character with  ü it seems.

- Is there a standard rule here? Should  ü always be replaced with v in pinyin programs?
- What about after the J, Q, X and Y letters where  ü is always implied, should I be hitting V or U on my keyboard?

Sorry for the simplistic question, I wish I could understand the sougou documentation, but it's still "chinese" to me. Thank you.

Comment: Only when there's ambiguity. For instance, lu is a valid pinyin so lü becomes lv in the IME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past (e.g. 80's to 90's), when the Chinese IME did not implement fuzzy logic, the rule was you should use `v` for and only for `ü` as you would write on paper. For example for J you should type `ju` not `jv`.

Now all the mainstream Chinese IME (MSPY, Sogou, Google Pinyin, etc.) has fuzzy logic built-in and enabled by default. This question isn't much relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0):

V is not used in Chinese as a  consonant (声母), it was used to be ü as a **vowel** (Chinese called 韵母), like

lv -> 绿
xv -> 许

Is there a standard rule here? Should ü always be replaced with v in pinyin programs?
**Yes**

What about after the J, Q, X and Y letters where ü is always implied, should I be hitting V or U on my keyboard?

**When used with JQXY ü is same as u in sogou , it is normal in internet ,  although they are 
different in  textbook.**

Answer (score -1):

A more direct answer:

- lv
- nv
- lve
- nve

Answer (score -1):

v is not an Alphabet in official PINYIN system but an International Phonetic Alphabet.
`ǘ` 读`愚,于,雨,遇`
But `Sougou` always using what is short for convenience.
It's the most popular Chinese Input Method in China even Apple set it as default in OSX Mavericks.
I think there are no strict rules,everything based on your own preferences.